# Android studio firebase + map

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

there is a project with a map. The API is there, everything works. I want to connect to firebase. but I can't. as I understand it, the fact is that I have a map and there is my own API, and another one in firebase. I did a test project with reading data from the database and everything works there. does not work in the map project.
[firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dswaW.png)
google-services.json download.

input class:

```
public class data_dev extends AppCompatActivity{

    private DatabaseReference myData;   //подключение к firebase
    private String USER_KEY="Bridge";     //ключ. имя первого уровня
    Intent intent;
    final int limit_index_csv = 5;   //для таблицы. до какого элемента считать. 2385
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.data_dev);
        myData= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(USER_KEY);  //объявил данные
    }
    public void OnClickSave_data(View view){
        //прием
        intent = getIntent();

        String id = myData.getKey();
        int i=0;

        data_Users dataus1=new data_Users(id,"1","2","3","4","5","6","7");
        myData.push().setValue(dataus1);
    }
}
```

list with new key does not appear. should appear here "Bridge"
[new kay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RqeB.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.  Thank you.

Comment: "but I can't" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. Please show us what you have tried and what the problem is.

Comment: @AlexMamo update

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo  new list should be created with the name "Bridge" and the numbers 1, 2,3 ... in "new kay" picture

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, but it's hard to be certain without also seeing the `data_Users` class. You might also want to test `myData.setValue(true);` to see if that simpler instruction works.

Comment: This question is already solved?

Comment: the issue remained unresolved. I still haven't figured out how to reconnect to another database (project) firebase. so I just created a duplicate of the android studio project and connected already in the new project to the database